# How to undefine defmethods

Tags: generics, lisp, elisp

How can I undefine `cl-defmethod`s I've defined for `cl-defgeneric`s without needing to restart emacs?

For example, given these

```
(cl-defgeneric my-fun (n &optional _arg) n)
(cl-defmethod my-fun ((n string)) (upcase n))
(cl-defmethod my-fun ((n integer)) (* n n))
(cl-defmethod my-fun (n &context (major-mode emacs-lisp-mode))
  (if (evenp n) n (cl-call-next-method (/ n 2))))
```

How could I remove one of the methods interactively? Eg. remove the method specialized for elisp buffers, so calling `(my-fun 9)` from an elisp buffer would just result
in 81, instead of passing through the current `major-mode` specialized method first?

Comment: It looks like you can't in any easy way.  A horrible workaround is to redefine the method to simply do a `(call-next-method)`.

Comment: @tfb smart hack, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This originated as a comment, but I think it might count as an answer in the absence of anything better.]

I think this is hard to do using `generic.el`.  However a trick to do something functionally equivalent is to replace the method you want to 'remove' by a definition which simply says `(call-next-method)`.  Once you've done that then the method is essentially no longer there functionally, except it will slow things down a bit.